# ADB doesn't detect Motorola Droid

Tags: motorola-droid, adb

I have a Motorola Droid1 phone, running android 2.2.3 (not rooted).  When I run `adb devices` it doesn't detect the Droid.  I checked in Device Manager on my 64bit Win8 machine, and I see an **Android ADB Interface** listed there.  I never had this problem with my other Motorola phones (Droid X1, Droid X2, Droid Bionic).

I have tried many things:
- reinstall Motorola USB drivers
- kill adb process
- kill adb server
- restart the machine
- factory-reset the phone
- pub 0x22B8 into adb_usb.ini

Nothing helps.  Has anybody experienced a similar issue?

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: Is USB debugging turned on on the phone?

Comment: EDIT: Moved this comment to an answer since it's as best as I've ever been able to do.

Answer (score 1):

I've never been able to get my Motorola Droid (first gen) to connect over ADB in Windows 8, even with all the above set. Other devices in Windows 8 64-bit work with those settings. Not my original Motorola Droid though.

But ADB works for me in Windows 7 64-bit, once all the above settings are also made. I think the modern ADB USB driver for Windows 8 only half supports devices as old as the original Droid. It's quite frustrating, but I don't know of any other way around this for now.

Comment: One solution I've discovered works well is to run VMWare with a linux client.  Then I can communicate with my Droid 1 from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem then tried to turn off USB debugging and then managed to connnect.